# RxJS: Timeout without Error/Complete

Tags: javascript, timeout, rxjs

Having a websocket connection, I try to get information if the connection is upright. That I try to do with RxJS and an interval. The problem is that after one timeout the stream ends and I want the interval to continue afterwards so that I can see if it already reconnected.

```js
    function listenToConnectionLost () {
        return rx.Observable
            .interval(5000) // every 5 seconds
            .flatMap(tryPing)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            // so I want to have either "connected" or "timeout" here
            // onNext I want to handle the different outputs 
        ;
    }

    function tryPing () {
        var pingPromise = getPingPromise();
        var pingObservable = rx.Observable
            .fromPromise(pingPromise)
            .timeout(5000)
            .catch(Rx.Observable.just('timeout')) // catches error, but
                                                  // completes the stream
        ;

        return pingObservable;
    }

    function getPingPromise () {
        // returns a promise, which resolves when connection is upright
    }
```

Here I also have a live example with a "faked" interval: http://jsbin.com/gazuvu/4/edit?js,console

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently the above posted code *is working*, because completed stream will be fed into the flatMap in `listenToConnectionLost`. I tested it by inserting the following code into `getPingPromise`.

```
function getPingPromise () {
  if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
    return $q.when('connected'); // resolves immediately
  }
  else {
    return $q.defer().promise; // never resolves, triggers timeout
  }
}
```